# Highline clobbering previous output

Tags: ruby, highline

*Using Highline v1.6.19*

When I run the following Ruby program:

```
require 'highline'

stdin = HighLine.new($stdin, $stdout)
stdin.ask("1 enter password: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
stdin.ask "2 enter something else: "
stdin.ask("3 enter password: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
stdin.ask "4 enter something else: "
```

The output looks like this while asking the first three questions:

```
1 enter password:
2 enter something else: whatever
3 enter password:
```

Then it asks for fourth time, and instead of placing the 4th line after the third, it overwrites the previous output from the second line:

```
1 enter password:
4 enter something else: whatever
3 enter password:
```

Any idea why or what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I get:

```
1 enter password: 
2 enter something else: hello
3 enter password: 
4 enter something else: goodbye
```

What os are you using?

Comment: Mac OSX (10.8.2), I get this on iTerm2 and Terminal.

Comment: Had a friend try, and it worked correctly for him, too. Any idea why mine would be off? :/ My readline was installed with homebrew, but it says it's keg only, not sure what else it could be.